# How to describe "diluted" words, whose meaning has become too ambiguous

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How to concisely and accurately describe the effect many words (usually adjectives/adverbs) are suffering from, where:

- they have a clear primary meaning but end up being used merely for emphasis, or to describe something similar but much less significant
- were you to use them with the primary meaning in mind, you'd need to clarify which it is to be understood, often for the message to even be noticed
- they are the most accurate words for what you have in mind, the lack of unambiguous drop-in replacements setting them apart from the many other words whose meaning drift does not have the same frustrating impact

Examples:

"Stop, you're **literally** killing me" (You are causing me lethal damage; not making me rotfl)

"**Uncanny** semblance" (saliently disturbing similarity, as in [uncanny valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley); not [just remarkable, amazing, significant, interesting, curious likeness](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25869/161482))

**[edit]** The focus is on the effect that has made the words difficult to use in their primary meaning.

Comment: I would just say that they are trite, or tired, or cliché.

Comment: Figurative means something completely different.  It means NOT LITERAL.

Comment: This sounds like [semantic bleaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization?wprov=sfsi1#Semantic_bleaching) or perhaps some other kind of grammaticalization (*obligorification*?).

Comment: "literally" is a special case, where people say "literally" when they actually mean the opposite, ie "figuratively".  They should literally be slapped.

Comment: The words the question asks about are Literally and Uncanny, which the OP seems to think are somehow lacking in "significance".

Comment: @warren-p Exactly. I've turned cursive to bold for visibility. As for "seems to think are somehow lacking" - were I to try to put "uncanny" in an opinion on a design, what % of the audience do you think would even read that as a bad thing?

Comment: @dan-bron Yeah, seems to be it, at least close enough. Will you make an answer out of it?

Comment: ***Figurative ‘literally’ in the OED***: *Hold the front pages, literally. Or not. There has been much excitement this week over the discovery that the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) has recorded a sense of the word literally that seems to cause particular irritation.* *I am speaking of its use in a sentence like “I literally died laughing and had to run out of the room before I disrupted the meeting”.*  http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/08/literally/

Comment: @kaay I'm actually not convinced myself, to tell you the truth. For example, I agree that *literally* has lost some of its former lexical (semantic) value, and it is used for emphasis, but while it might be on the path, it is not yet a "function word", and so it's hard to say whether it's undergoing semantic bleaching or just normal language evolution (like "awful", eg, which originally meant "inspiring awe", as opposed to disgust, rejection, or fear). But if you're convinced, you're welcome to make an answer out of "semantic bleaching" yourself, I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the question has no answer, but the closest term to what is described is [semantic bleaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization#Semantic_bleaching) (a good explanation [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Bleaching.htm)).

Credit goes to Dan Bron, upvote his comment if you agree.